# Idris in atom editor, "Couldn't find Idris executable" error

Tags: executable, atom-editor, typechecking, idris

I am currently trying to download and use Idris for Atom and use it's editor. I downloaded Hackage and then installed idris on my computer from there and then installed the idris package on atom, and when ever I type in the program it highlights like Idris should, but when I type check it I am getting two errors, "Couldn't find idris executable: Couldn't find idris executable at "Idris"" and "The idris compiler was closed or crashed: It (probably) crashed with error code : -2".

[picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO03G.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [readme](https://github.com/idris-hackers/atom-language-idris#usage) for the plugin says, you need to set the "Idris location:" setting in the plugin config to the path where you have installed the Idris binary.